# java.util.List element to string Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing a program with database.

I'm querying the database to get one item from it using a `org.hibernate.Query` object.

I need to set the content of this item as value of a `JTextField` component.

The problem is that I don't know how to convert a `java.util.List` item to one `String` which I can use in `setText(getCodeOfSub(String nameOfTheSubj))` method:

```
public String getCodeOfSub(String nameOfTheSubj){

  Session session =  Service.getSession();
  org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT subject.subjectCode, subject.name  " +
      "FROM SubjectEntity subject WHERE subject.name="+"'"
      +nameOfTheSubj+"'");

  java.util.List results = query.list();

  if(!results.isEmpty()) {
    return String.valueOf(results.get(0));
  }
  session.close();
  return null;
}
```

Comment: A "`java.util.List` item" is just an `Object`. You can use the `toString()` method: `return results.get(0).toString()`. If the display is not satisfying, investigate the type of the object `results.get(0)` to get the information out of it.

Comment: What kind of `String` should the result be? Is `results.toString()` fine?

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;@2a1504f3` this is a result of `results.get(0).toString()` metohod...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would get when calling the `org.hibernate.Query#list` is a `List<Object[]>` meaning a list of rows where each row will hold an object representation but in your case it will be an array of two items being the *subject.code* and *subject.name*.

So in essence, `results.get(0)` will return a `Object[]` where:

- `results.get(0)[0]` -> *subject.code*
- `results.get(0)[1]` -> *subject.name*

So when calling the `String.valueOf(results.get(0))`, you will be trying to get the string representation of the array of objects, which is will not be what you are expecting... the different items somehow separated but will be a raw array followed by a hash representation.

What would be the simplest way to get out your items representation using the items `toString` method would be to use the static utility `Arrays.asList(Object[])`, i.e:

```
//...
return String.valueOf(Arrays.asList(results.get(0)));
//...
```

Here down what is stated about the `toString` method of a collection:

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified
>   array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's
>   elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are
>   separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).
>   Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(int). Returns
>   "null" if a is null.

To get a better representation of your items, you may need to process them manually using some utility method... I would suggest the [`Joiner` from *google-collections* library](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html).